# How to return generated command string only when using PHP-FFMpeg libarary

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg-php

How can I see which command string generated for below example code

```
$advancedMedia = $ffmpeg->openAdvanced(array('video_1.mp4', 'video_2.mp4'));
$advancedMedia->filters()
    ->custom('[0:v][1:v]', 'hstack', '[v]');
$advancedMedia
    ->map(array('0:a', '[v]'), new X264('aac', 'libx264'), 'output.mp4')
    ->save();
```

looking for **toString()** for `FFMpeg` class or https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's a method called [`getFinalCommand`](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/631f5ac5d603413f1958024b89d7eace230cad4f/src/FFMpeg/Media/Video.php#L106) in the audio and video classes by the `PHP-FFMpeg` package.

Access it via the `get` method:

```php
$advancedMedia
    ->get()
    ->getFinalCommand();
```

Untested code.